# WSL2 環境で Ubuntu が起動できない

Tags: ubuntu, wsl

Windows10でUbuntuを起動したあと「WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800701bc」というエラーメッセージが表示されたので，Linux カーネル更新プログラムパッケージをダウンロードしましたが解決しませんでした．対処方法を教えてください．

**追記:**
ご回答ありがとうございます．
以下，分かる範囲で補足します．

私が試しているのはWSL2の方だと思います．

ご紹介いただいた
https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/wsl/wsl2.html
について言うと，「Hyper-Vのチェック
Linux 用 Windows サブシステムのチェック，
仮想マシンプラットフォームのチェック」
のところはできています．

ただし，「Windows の PowerShell を，
管理者として実行する」のところで，
Windows Subsubsystem for Linux を有効化しようと
するとき，コマンドを入力すると何故か文字化けが生じます．

Ubuntuのインストールは完了しています．

Comment: 質問に記述された内容が少なすぎて、どんな環境・版数と手順でどこまで実行してどんなエラーになったのかといったことが明確にならないと適切な助言は難しいでしょう。例えばこんな記事が参考になるかもしれませんが。[WSL 2 のインストール，Ubuntu 20.04, 18.04 のインストールと利用（Windows 上）](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/wsl/wsl2.html), [Windows 10 用 Windows Subsystem for Linux のインストール ガイド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Comment: Windows 上で Ubuntu を利用する方法はいくつかあります。今回はエラーメッセージを見る限り WSL を利用なさっているようですが、WSL にも WSL 1 と WSL 2 があります。どのような環境でどのように作業なさったときにエラーが出たのか、[edit] して詳しく書いていただけないでしょうか。たとえば Windows 10 のバージョン情報や、使ったコマンドの情報が欲しいです。

Answer (score 1):

根本的な解決になるかわからないですが、Windows11にアップデートするとWSL2～Docker環境構築までの諸々のセットアップがスムーズになります。

https://kyo.simodake.work/20210828_wsl_docker_jupyter/

Answer (score 0):

文字化けするのは、システムロケールのせいかもしれません。
以下記事の「システム ロケールの変更(インストール後)」を試してみると、文字化けせずに実行結果が見れるかもしれません。

[システム ロケールの変更(インストール後) | Windowsの初期インストールの注意事項](https://zenn.dev/zunda_pixel/articles/f9c90b110b362a#%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0-%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4(%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E5%BE%8C))